# Relativistic Particle Motion and Numerical Methods

Tags: special-relativity, computational-physics, coulombs-law

I want to be able to show the relativistic motion of a particle in a static electric field produced by a proton at the origin: $$ \vec{E}  = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r} $$

The acceleration of an electron is can be derived from Newton's 2nd Law to be:
$$\vec {a} ={\frac{1}{m_{0}\gamma (\vec{v} )}}\left(\vec{F} -{\frac{(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{F} )\vec{v} }{c^2}}\right)$$

Where,
$$ \vec{F}  = -\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q^2}{r^2}\hat{r} $$

If I am going to put this into a simulation. Say I use Euler's Method. Can I calculate the velocity and the position the same as I would for non relativistic motion and just use the relativistic acceleration? (Also assume I break them into their proper components):
$$ v_{n+1} = v_n + a_nt $$
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n + v_nt $$

I am having some difficulties with my program (could even be a typo), but just want to make sure that I am thinking correctly here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Euler's method is just a method for solving differential equations. You have the differential equations, so you can use the method. Although what you mean by 'proper components' I'm a bit confused by.

Comment: @jacob1729 Sorry about that. In this situation "proper" is definitely not the best word choice. I just meant to say I need to break down the acceleration into its components first before solving for x and y. Anyway, thanks for the comment. I just wanted to make sure I was doing this right.

Comment: This looks correct to me. I would say so in an answer, but I don't think the SE software allows answers that short.